# Low-quality answers

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

A bunch of answers just came into the low quality review queue (coincidentally, many by the same user...) and they all share one characteristic: they are incorrect, but they do attempt to answer the question. Just to confirm: because they attempt to answer the question, I should click "looks OK"?

Side note: like I said, many were by the same user, and the answers were ranging from years ago to recent. Was someone digging through the user's answers? Seems a little too many for coincidence.

Comment: Is this the low quality review queue?

Comment: See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9027/50583

Comment: @DavidZ, yes, this is the low quality review queue.

Comment: In that case @ACuriousMind's comment is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the Answers (rather than the Questions) were from years ago? I have noticed some new users posting brief, comment-like answers to old Questions.

My view is the same as that of Kyle Kanos expressed in these 2 posts :

[What to do with Low Quality posts that you just can't delete](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5995/what-to-do-with-low-quality-posts-that-you-just-cant-delete?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Is it appropriate to use the low quality review system to get rid of 'bad' answers?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-low-quality-review-system-to-get-rid-of-bad-answe?rq=1)

The way to deal with "bad" or "incorrect" answers is to comment and/or down-vote, not to delete.